# Changing Time Format in R

Tags: r, datetime

My data contains columns containing the start and end times, but they're both encoded as follows:

```
630
545
1130
1525
1415
```

How do I convert these to

```
6:30
5:45
11:30
15:25
14:15
```

Comment: `sub("(\\d{2})$", ":\\1", your_data)`

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- c(630, 545, 1130, 1525, 1415)

sub("(\\d{2})$", ":\\1", a)

[1] "6:30"  "5:45"  "11:30" "15:25" "14:15"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to convert `number` to `time format` values:

```
numbers <- c(630, 545, 1130, 1525, 1415)

time <- substr(as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04.0f", numbers), format='%H%M'), 12, 16)
time
```

Output:

```
[1] "06:30" "05:45" "11:30" "15:25" "14:15"
```